# Clicking picture in one form should display text in label box in another form, C#, VS 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have windows form application which have 2 forms, the 1st form has a label, the 2nd form has a picture, clicking on the picture should give a text in the label of the first form. Form 1 has a constructor which takes id as its parameter. I tried different methods but I am unable to get display text in label box

Comment: Please share your work.

Comment: Did you already try to put text into a label in the same form?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand, but if my answer doesn't work can you explain more about what you're trying to accomplish, possibly with examples of code you've already tried?

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}


public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 Form2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Form2 = new Form2();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int DummyID = 4;
        this.Form2.UpdateLabel(DummyID);
    }
}
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {

    }

    internal void UpdateLabel(int ID)
    {
        label1.Text = $"Picture ID {ID} Was Clicked!";
    }
}
```